# How can my bash script detect that tomcat is fully stopped?

Tags: bash, tomcat

I have tomcat downloaded on my computer (not installed as a service).
I am writing a script that upgrades a webapp running on the tomcat server. The script roughly works like this:

- Stop tomcat
- Perform several upgrade operations
- Start tomcat

When performing the upgrade operations, I need to know that tomcat is fully stopped. However if I run `$TOMCAT_HOME/bin/catalina.sh stop` then that script exits before tomcat is actually stopped and if I execute the upgrade operations while tomcat is still running that might cause things to crash. In addition, the upgrade operations may finish quickly and this can cause the tomcat startup to execute before the shutdown is complete which causes tomcat to crash.

Right now my solution is to wait for 5 seconds after the shutdown is initiated but I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution to the problem.

Comment: Not sure. The other question was asked later than mine so if anything, it is the duplicate. The problem the other person has is that the command is not working, at least not for 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

One way to verify whether the process is still running is by using its process id. Depending on your installation, you should be able to find the process id of your tomcat server in:

```
/opt/tomcat/catalina.pid
```

In theory, if this file is empty, then the process should have ended although depending on the implementation and certain circumstances (tomcat crashing?) this might not be true. To be safe, you can take the pid found in this file and just check whether this process is still running.

```
ps -p <pid>
```

The above command will return the pid, the time and the command of the process if it is still active.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to check if a certain port (the one that Tomcat uses) can be bound. If you can't bind on this port, it means that Tomcat is still running.

Anyway, Felix's solution is more appropriate and it's probably better to use it. I only wrote my suggestion in order to provide more alternatives, also not all Tomcat installations have `catalina.pid` (at least the default one doesn't).